# Displaying FAQ and answers in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8. I need to display FAQ's and it answers in a page. There is content type called FAQ. How can I do this with content type FAQ.

Is FAQ module required for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, FAQ module is not required (BTW, it is currently in dev status for Drupal 8). Just use `Views` module to create a /faq page.

Comment: How to have Q & A functionality in D8?